# Java static methods with class level variables

Tags: java, multithreading, static

I have static method when multiple threads are accessing , will the data updated incorrectly,

```
public class A
{

    private static B b=null;

    public static B create()
    {
        b= new B();
        return b;
    }

    public static B process()
    {
        // doing some processing with b;
        return b;
    }
}
```

If multiple threads are accessing simultaneously, Will B get affected?

Comment: Look into synchronized(), volatile, and possibly a thread-safe Singleton pattern.

Comment: That code doesn't even compile in its current form..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect the value and ensure it is updated correctly, then you should make the method synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

No, because `b` exists on object level and is not statically accessible.

Comment: Sorry ,  B is also static member only . I have updated the code now.

Answer (score 0):

No one can tell until we see the way you access and work on `b`.

However, one thing I can tell is, static or not is usually not a main factor that affect thread-safetiness.